# Power BI code for filtering in M Language

Tags: powerbi, m

Please let me know why the below is not filtering

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("localhost\SQLEXPRESS", "master"),
    dbo_dqra = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="dqra"]}[Data],
    WTF = Table.SelectRows(dqRA as table, "column 0" < 25 as function) 
in
    dbo_dqra
```

first line is let
2nd line is source
3rd line is db
4th line is wtf
5th line is in
6th line is db

Comment: instead of "in dbo_dqra" you want "in WTF"

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is being applied in the step that you have labeled "WTF", but the last clause of your query is returning the prior step, "dbo_dqra"

Also, there's some syntax that's wrong.  You don't need those "as table" / "as function" remarks, and the column should be wrapped in brackets, not quotes.

Try this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("localhost\SQLEXPRESS", "master"),
    dbo_dqra = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="dqra"]}[Data],
    WTF = Table.SelectRows(dbo_dqra, each [column 0] < 25) 
in
    WTF
```

Comment: Additionally, that first arg to `Table.SelectRows` should reference the second variable, `dbo_dqra`. The variable being referenced, `dqRA` doesn't exist in the scope of this query. So unless that's some other query's name, it should probably read as `WTF = Table.SelectRows(dbo_dqra, ...)`

Comment: fixed. I got lazy on that.